# Python - Understanding the send function of a generator

Tags: python, generator, yield, yield-keyword

I'm studying in Python `yield` and find that `yield` is not only the way in which generators output a return value but also a way to put values into a generator. For example the following code

```
def f():
    print (yield),
    print 0,
    print (yield),
    print 1

g = f()
g.send(None)
g.send('x')
g.send('y')
```

In the global scope it `send`s value `'x'`, `'y'` to the generator and thus in `f` it will output `x 0 y 1`. But I cannot understand

- There are 2 `yield`s but 3 `send`s. Why should it send `None` at the first time?
- It throws a `StopIteration` at the last `send`. Is there any way to avoid this exception?

Could anyone please explain that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.send):

> When `send()` is called to start the generator, it must be called with `None` as the argument, because there is no `yield` expression that could receive the value.

As for the exception, you can't really avoid it. The generator throws this exception when it's done iterating, so instead of avoiding it, just catch it:

```
g = f()

try:
    g.send(None)
    g.send('x')
    g.send('y')
except StopIteration:
    print 'Done'
```

Comment: There is a way to avoid the exception. Put an extra `yield` at the end of the generator function. The generator will not close, but will eventually be garbage collected.

Comment: g.send(None) makes no sense，although must be added